# IntEnum subclass does not compare properly

Tags: python, enums, enumeration

I'm trying to subclass the IntEnum to start members' value at a certain value and then automatically set the value for subsequent members.  This is my class:

```python
class Abc(IntEnum):
  def __init__(self, n=100):
    super().__init__()
    self._value_ = n + len(self.__class__.__members__)

  A = () # 100
  B = () # 101

Abc.A == Abc.B # expects False, but gets True
```

As shown above the comparison between the members is not correct.  When printing out Abc.**dict**, I noticed that it _value2member_map_ does not look correct either.

```
mappingproxy({'A': <Abc.A: 100>,
          'B': <Abc.B: 101>,
          '__doc__': 'An enumeration.',
          '__init__': <function __main__.Abc.__init__>,
          '__module__': '__main__',
          '__new__': <function enum.Enum.__new__>,
          '_generate_next_value_': <function enum.Enum._generate_next_value_>,
          '_member_map_': OrderedDict([('A', <Abc.A: 100>),
                       ('B', <Abc.B: 101>)]),
          '_member_names_': ['A', 'B'],
          '_member_type_': int,
          '_value2member_map_': {0: <Abc.B: 101>}})
```

Notice how '_value2member_map_' has key 0 instead of the expected values 100 and 101.  I must be missing something in the init function, but I could not figure out how to properly do what I intended.  Any help is appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: You're trying to rely on undocumented internal behavior of the `enum` module. Even if you got that right in a way that happened to work with whichever version of Python you're using, is that really something you want to do?

Answer (score 4):

First, there's a more idiomatic—and dead simple—way to do what you seem to be trying to do:

```
class Abc(IntEnum):
    A = 100
    B = auto()
```

Or, given that you're putting 100 and 101 in as comments anyway, live code is always better than comments:

```
class Abc(IntEnum):
    A = 100
    B = 101
```

The fact that you're *not* doing either of those is a signal to the reader that you're probably doing to do something more complicated. Except that, as far as I can tell, you aren't, so this is misleading.

Plus, you're combining two patterns that have directly opposite connotations: as [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#omitting-values) say, using the `()` idiom "signifies to the user that these values are not important", but using `IntEnum` obviously means that the numeric values of these enumeration constants are not just important but the whole point of them.

Not only that, but the user has to read through your method code to figure out what those important numeric values are, instead of just immediately reading them off.

---

Anyway, if you want to get this to work, the problem is that replacing `_value_` after initialization isn't documented to do any good, and in fact it doesn't.

What you want to override is `__new__`, not `__init__`, as in [the auto-numbering example in the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#using-a-custom-new).

But there are two differences here (both related to the fact that you're using `IntEnum` instead of `Enum`):

- You cannot call `object.__new__`, because an `IntEnum` is an `int`, and `object.__new__` can't be used on instances of builtin types like `int`. You can figure out the right base class dynamically from looking through `cls`'s mro, or you can just hardcode `int` here.
- You don't need an intermediate base class here to do the work. (You might still want one if you were going to create multiple auto-numbered `IntEnum`s, of course.)

So:

```
class Abc(IntEnum):
    def __new__(cls, n=100):
        value = len(cls.__members__) + n
        obj = int.__new__(cls, value)
        obj._value_ = value
        return obj
    A = ()
    B = ()
```

Comment: I am not trying to do anything special. Your first example is exactly what I need. Thank you very much.